# error: unexpected argument 'i686-pc-windows-msvc' found

Tags: tauri

пытался скомпилировать приложение с поддержкой для 32-битных компов, ввел команду которая была в доках (https://tauri.app/v1/guides/building/windows) но что-то пошло не так:

```
PS C:\generator\tauri-app> npm run tauri build --target i686-pc-windows-msvc
```

tauri-app@0.0.0 tauri

tauri build i686-pc-windows-msvc

error: unexpected argument 'i686-pc-windows-msvc' found

Usage: cargo.exe build [OPTIONS]

For more information, try '--help'.

```
    Error failed to build app: failed to build app
```

PS C:\generator\tauri-app>